# Division returns opposite (negative) results

Tags: c++, c++11, division

Whenever I'm trying to divide two integers, I am getting some odd results when the integers are bigger than `21474836` - I thought that it's the case of some data-type limitations, but the `int`eger is obviously much bigger: `2147483647`.

As I said, this happens only when two of the integers are bigger than `21474836`.

Working (because the integers are lower than `21474836`):

```
(11474836 * 100) / 11474836 // returns 100
```

Not working:

```
(211474836 * 100) / 211474836 // returns 0, should 100
(31474830 * 100) / 31474837 // returns -99, should 99~
(40000000 * 100) / 41474837 // returns -7, should 96~
```

**See the live demo here**: http://ideone.com/lAeneM

What is the problem?

Comment: seems to me like homework question...

Comment: I wonder what you think multiplication does...

Comment: Try replacing `100` by `100ULL`.

Comment: Try to divide first then multiply, then it will be in range of integer, As `(40000000 * 100)` will be out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotten mixed up, 2147483647 is the upper range of a signed long. Integers cap out at 65535 - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/2044255) for details.

Changing the values to unsigned longs gives you the range (0 to 4294967295) needed to solve your issue:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Ret1: " << (21474837UL * 100UL) / 21474837UL << endl; // should result 100
    cout << "Ret2: " << (31474830UL * 100UL) / 31474837UL << endl; // should result 99~
    cout << "Ret3: " << (40000000UL * 100UL) / 41474837UL << endl; // should result 96~

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I was simply too tired to notice that. I very appreciate this detailed answer :-)

Comment: Consider that if you want to allow signed/negative values (not needed for your calculations in the example though) you can change the `UL` (unsigned long) with `L`(long)!

Answer (score 2):

When you multiply those values by 100 then the result overflows and set the highest bit, bringing the value into negative territory.

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget that `211474836 * 100` is bigger than `INT_MAX` so you get over the border of an integer. Interpret the values as an int64 and you should get the right results.